# Azure Service Management API authentication using Azure Active Directory Oauth

Tags: azure, oauth, cloud

I'd like to authenticate to the Azure Service Management API using Azure AD through curl.

I [set up an application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460782.aspx) within my default directory. In this free trial subcription that's the only directory I have.

When I target the oauth token endpoint I receive a JWT.

```
curl --data "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<my_client_id>&client_secret=<my_encoded_secret>&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net" https://login.windows.net/<my_tenant_id>/oauth2/token
```

But when I use that token to list my subscription details I receive an error:

```
curl -H "x-ms-version: 2014-06-01" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer <my_token>" \
     https://management.core.windows.net/<my_subscription_id>/

    <Error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Code>ForbiddenError</Code>
      <Message>The server failed to authenticate the request. Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.</Message>
    </Error>
```

I have granted permissions to the Service Management API for the application as "Delegated permissions", because "Application permissions" are not available.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Matt, any luck with this? I'm facing similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible due to the *Application Permissions: 0* setting for the Service Management API. The *client_credentials* grant type uses credentials from the application (client_id and client_secret), and since the application does not have permissions for this API the call fails.

Since the Service Management API will not allow application permissions of any kind, we must use the [authorization_code grant type](https://ahmetalpbalkan.com/blog/azure-rest-api-with-oauth2/) or some other method to obtain a user token.

Comment: Does this mean that we can only authenticate a Microsoft account with our AAD application interactively using the browser popup? I tried to create an AAD application with a service principal, but I cannot access the old service management REST APIs due to the same Forbidden error.

Comment: If the AAD application is added as a Native app then you can authenticate with the service principal credentials and the client ID of the AAD app. The browser popup method is required if the AAD application is added as a Web app.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. But I am still unable to access the Service Management API when authenticating with the service principal of the native AAD app (probably because the "Access service management" permission of the app is only a delegated permission and not an application permission).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the Azure Service Management API permissions cannot be configured through the Azure Portal API.

The full solition is here:

https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/02/azure-rest-apis-postman-2021/

The solution lies in using the Azure CLI to create a service principal that already has the rights assigned.

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac
```

You can go directly to https://shell.azure.com/ and execute the command.

Be sure to save the resulting credential data securely.