# Azure Service Management API access via AD Oauth fails

Tags: c#, api, azure, service, oauth

II'm having same issue as this - [Azure Service Management API authentication using Azure Active Directory Oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003820/azure-service-management-api-authentication-using-azure-active-directory-oauth) with slightly different scenario.

I'm running a headless app (with nunit to run integration tests) setup just as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460782.aspx to get stage deployment url which is dynamic in all it's glory.

I can call production url and run tests while authenticating requests with AD in a headless fashion but not service management api. I've given permission to service management api for the service as in the walk-through.

Also, I get token via client credential calling :

```
result = context.AcquireToken(
  "https://management.core.windows.net/",
  "{clientId}",
  clientCredential,   // had client id and key
  new Uri("{redirectUri}"));
```

A get Unauthorized: A Security token exception occurred for the received JWT token.

The Get deployment url used is here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx
I double-ched subscrption id, sevice names etc.

Anybody have insights on what's failing in spite of a seemingly valid token?

Is this ever known to be working with app key? I  can't find a single example yet.

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Comment: No, none of the credentials (azure AD account username/pwd) or clientId/appkey work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AcquireToken(string resource, string clientId, UserCredential userCrential) overload instead. This is the function [designed](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/USING-ADAL-NET-TO-AUTHENTICATE-USERS-VIA-USERNAMEPASSWORD/) for headless apps.

Since the Service Management API only allows Delegated Permissions you need to supply credentials for a user (username and password) instead of an application (client id and key).